# Can 2 different BU see only records created by themselves on a shared DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sfmc-business-unit

So, I have Parent BU which has a shared Data Extension with two child BU (let's call them Alpha and Beta).

Now, I want both Aplha and Beta to be able to write data on such shared DE, but I want them to only read, edit and delete records created by themselves. So Alpha souldn't be able to view Beta's record and viceversa.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfotunately it is not, the access is not based on the records inside the Data Extension but the Data Extension **location** itself.

You will need to create and use different Shared Folder for each BU, with different Data Extension inside of it. 
Then you'll be able to merge these two DE's into one with SQL in your parent BU, if required.